# echo an array value based on a mysql value

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Have a hard time trying to echo the $status arrays value into the cell where the $row['status'] is.
Right now it prints the DB values of 0-3. if it is a "0" print uploaded.....

```
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$status = array('uploaded', 'processing', 'error', 'closed');
?>
<tr align="center">
<td><?php echo $row['case_id']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['doctor']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['upload_date']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['service_date']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['status']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['message']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php
};
```

Comment: As you already accessed the values from your db query, just use the variable as index, e.g. `$status[$row["status"]]`

Comment: `<td><?php echo $status[$row['status']]; ?></td>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just echo `$status` using `$row['status']` as the key:

```
<td><?php echo $status[$row['status']]; ?></td>
```

Comment: What if I wanted to add color the the row, can I use an array within the first array?

As :
<?php echo $color $status[$row['status']]; ?>
or

Comment: Assuming you had a `$color` array, same thing: `echo $color[$row['status']];`